# Implement IConnectionPointContainer on an object extending from COleDocument (instead of COleControl)

Tags: com, mfc, ole

Has anybody had any experience with COM / MFC trying to implement IConnectionPointContainer on an object extending from COleDocument (instead of COleControl) ? Can somebody please provide any tips, or a pointer to a guide on how to do this ? I need to implement notifications for objects that listen to changes to the document, which are made as part of implementations of another interface which is implemented by the Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC connection macros are not specific to COleControl but CCmdTarget. You can use DECLARE_CONNECTION_MAP/BEGIN_CONNECTION_MAP etc [as long as your class is derived from CCmdTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa236917%28v=VS.60%29.aspx), and in this case, COleDocument is.

Suggested reading:

[TN038: MFC/OLE IUnknown Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hhehwba%28v=VS.100%29)

[Connpts.exe sample demonstrates how to implement connection points and connection point sinks in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152087)

Comment: I've actually already tried that, and when I compile, I get "error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'class CMyDoc*' to 'class ATL::_ICPLocator<&struct _GUID const IID_IMyEventSink> *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast"

Comment: I've now managed to get my code compiling using the advice in this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41yhk4w0(v=vs.80).aspx , however, whenever I try to advise a sink, I get error code 0x80004002 returned from AtlAdvise, which is E_NOINTERFACE.  I've tried following the advice here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183216/en-us , but with no success. Am I just missing something ? My sink interface is IDual, and from what I've seen it is possible to have multiple IDual interfaces implemented by an object.

Comment: Debug the function, which step failed? QI or IconnectionPointContainer  or at FindConnectionPoint?

Comment: The QueryInterface call is what fails. My object that's supposed to provide the ConnectionPointContainer extends from COleDocument and nothing else.

Comment: I've also verified that I'm calling EnableConnections() in the constructor of my document

Comment: I found the answer: I had to add an INTERFACE_PART to my interface map, outlined in this article to get COleDocument (and any other CCmdTarget descendant) to properly implement IConnectionPointContainer : http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0598/wicked0598.aspx